# can not scroll table up and down after using animation and a navigation bar disappears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My first view contains a button and after pressing a button, i will end up with the second view. what I have done is

```
FirstViewController.m

- (void)pushToWishList {
    SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil ];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

SecondViewController is an UIViewController such that :

SecondViewController.h :

> @interface SecondViewController :
>   UIViewController

SecondViewController.m

> ```
> self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden       = NO;
> self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton                 = NO;
> self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor   = [UIColor blackColor];
> ```

What is happening is the top navigation is disppearing and the UITableView in my second view can not be scrolled up and down. My program is crashed whenever I try to do this.

Please advice me on this issue. Any comments are welcomed here.

Answer (score 0):

First off its easier to not `addSubview:` just use this code to turn your page:

```
- (IBAction)myCart:(id)sender; {
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

This will allow your tableView to scroll! Also, your method return type is void, if you are using a button to call this method, you need to change the return type to `IBAction` which works for buttons.